# Error when trying to divide value after calling getAmountsOut from uniswap router 02

Tags: javascript, uniswap, react

I am having a lot of problems implement a swap via metamask using the uniswap router 02. I am able to call the getAmountsOut function but get an error when trying to do the following:

```
const getAmountOutMin = async () => {
                const amounts = await quickswap.methods.getAmountsOut(amountIn, [baseContract, targetContract]).call();
                console.log(amounts)
                setAmountOutMin(amounts[1].sub(amounts[1].div(10)));
                console.log(amountOutMin)
            }
```

I get the following error:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): amounts[1].div is not a function
getAmountOutMin
  133 |     const amounts = await quickswap.methods.getAmountsOut(amountIn, [baseContract, targetContract]).call();
  134 |     console.log(amounts)
  135 |     //Our execution price will be a bit different, we need some flexbility
> 136 |     setAmountOutMin(amounts[1].sub(amounts[1].div(10)));
      | ^  137 |     console.log(amountOutMin)
  138 | }
  139 | getAmountOutMin();
```

When I log the value of amounts in the console I get this:

```
[
    "1000000000000000000",
    "2767484742082040"
]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The error is quite clear `amounts[1].div is not a function`. You are calling a function `div` from `amounts[1]` that doesn't exist. From the logged data it seems is returning strings instead of numbers.

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I had to convert the string to a number then convert it back to a string when calling the swap function. What confused me is that I watched a video and the creator did not convert amounts[1] to a number in his code, so I figured the sub and div functions were able to do this percent calculation on strings. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Ismael for helping solve the issue.

The problem was solved by converting the amounts[1] to a number. Here's what I did and it works:

```
// in useeffect
const getAmountOutMin = async () => {
                setAmounts(await contract.methods.getAmountsOut(amountIn, [baseAddress, targetAddress]).call()))}
// minimum value is 95% of original
const amountOut1 = (Math.round(Number(amounts[1]) * 0.95)).toString()
// amountOutMin input for swapping functions such as SwapExactETHForTokens
setAmountOutMin(ethers.utils.parseUnits(amountOut1, 'wei'))
```